# Flutter: How to make a widget sticky on an image

Tags: flutter, resize

I am creating a website in flutter. One section is called 'About us' with a group picture of the team (I replaced the actual image for privacy reasons):

[image: 'About us' screenshot]

As you can see there are 5 buttons in the image. Each one should be placed on one person, so that when I click on it, I get information about that individual person.
There is a problem as soon as I scale the website and the image shifts and shrinks or enlarges as a result.

For this widget I am using a Stack with the image on its bottom and the buttons on top of it in a row:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/images/test_team.jpg'),
        const Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MemberButton(memberType: MemberType.stichel),
            MemberButton(memberType: MemberType.ozzi),
            MemberButton(memberType: MemberType.luis),
            MemberButton(memberType: MemberType.dan),
            MemberButton(memberType: MemberType.atjan),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The widget MemberButton looks like this:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double buttonSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.035;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      child: Lottie.asset(
        'assets/lottie/pulse.json',
        width: buttonSize,
        height: buttonSize,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
```

The issue with the Row implementation is that I cannot place them individually on the persons, I guess.

Another implementation was the use of a LayoutBuilder due to a recommendation of ChatGPT:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/test_team.jpg'),
            _buildMemberButton(0.12, 0.25, MemberType.stichel, constraints),
            _buildMemberButton(0.158, 0.21, MemberType.ozzi, constraints),
            _buildMemberButton(0.196, 0.25, MemberType.luis, constraints),
            _buildMemberButton(0.238, 0.23, MemberType.dan, constraints),
            _buildMemberButton(0.275, 0.215, MemberType.atjan, constraints),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMemberButton(double leftFraction, double topFraction, MemberType memberType, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return Positioned(
      left: leftFraction * constraints.maxWidth,
      top: topFraction * constraints.maxHeight,
      child: MemberButton(memberType: memberType),
    );
  }
```

This looks like this (let's assume the buttons were placed on the persons):

[image: interactive image with LayoutBuilder]

But even with this implemenation as soon as I resize Chrome, the buttons do not move according to the relative size of the image, so they don't stick on the persons:
[Link to screen capture](https://youtu.be/fWMSHtSC8rE)

So my questions is, what is the best way to make these buttons stick on the image so they stay in the right place while resizing the browser.

Comment: If you want to do something like this you will need to have individual elements here, each person will be a separate image and your background will be a separate image then you will stick the button atop these individual images, there is no other way to achieve this even on web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that the buttons are not anchored to the image size to be adjusted proportionally.

I tried again using your method and I think it works better, I only had to adjust a little detail, use the same constraints, and establish an aspect ratio, to preserve the proportions.

Also if you use the constraints you can scale the buttons

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                constraints: constraints,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/components/test.png'), fit: BoxFit.contain),
                ),
              ),
              _buildMemberButton(0.5, 0.3, constraints),
              _buildMemberButton(0.15, 0.3, constraints),
              _buildMemberButton(0.65, 0.3, constraints),
              _buildMemberButton(0.3, 0.3, constraints),
              _buildMemberButton(0.8, 0.3, constraints),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    )))

Widget _buildMemberButton(double leftFraction, double topFraction, BoxConstraints constraints) {
return Positioned(
  left: leftFraction * constraints.maxWidth,
  top: topFraction * constraints.maxHeight,
  child: Container(
    width: constraints.maxWidth / 50,
    height: constraints.maxWidth / 50,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi Alejo, thanks for your quick reply. I tried your code, but with my buttons instead of the containers you used. As you can see in the following video, your solution works quite well, but the buttons move significantly upwards and very slightly in the X direction when resizing. Is there a way to fix this?

[screen capture](https://youtu.be/xez7gH1jAI4)

Comment: And what would actually be even better is if I could place the buttons individually instead of in a row, as the people in my picture are not evenly distributed and are also different sizes. Is it possible to place the buttons each with a Positioned widget and leave their position the same relative to the image when resizing?

Comment: Mmm I understand, we can mix it up with what you did, if you can pass me some of your code I can help you a little more.

Comment: I will edit the post, try the new one and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That works very well, thank you Alejo!